# Python changes are not reflected in a running app

Tags: python

I've decided to make a simple Telegram Bot in order to learn a bit of Python.
I have a main.py that imports and executes another file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import butlerr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    butlerr.main()
```

I run that file

```
> python src/main.py
```

But if I make a change in butlerr.py, that's not reflected in the running app. I imagine I won't see changes in a running app. It works if I stop the command and re-run it, obviously.

I figure that's probably not the way to develop. Is there a more seamless way to make changes and see them immediately? I saw a blog post where they create like a web server, but I think that doesn't work on my case.

I closed a question I previously made cause I thought it was a docker issue, but it was not.

Comment: It generally doesn't make sense to swap modules in a running process. The objects that were already created have obviously been created with the old version of a module, so they won't be compatible with a new version of the module. For example, ``butlerr.main()`` would have already been called and *be running* – the effect of swapping it with a new version would be undefined.

Comment: Can you look at this article, maybe it works for you;  https://towardsdatascience.com/2-tools-to-automatically-reload-when-python-files-change-90bb28139087

Comment: Then how's the development cycle? 
I mean, I want to code and then see the changes when talking to the bot. Right now, I have to make the change, stop the running process, re-run it, then talk to the bot again.

(Sorry if the question is stupid, today's literally the first day I'm writing a line of python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called hot-reloading.
every famous python framework has the hot-reloading option ( so you can turn it on and off )

first check if your package has this feature or not.

Then if it did not have hot-reloading option, you can run your python app using [this package](https://github.com/breuleux/jurigged)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much. https://github.com/JorgeAnzola/butlerr/blob/master/Dockerfile#L11